# Integration Testing the Canvas

Tags: canvas, integration-testing, jasmine

I have been experimenting with methods over the past couple of weeks trying to find the best method to use BDD for a web application that is relient on the HTML5 canvas element, and user interaction with it.

I have been using Jasmine and Cucumber with Rspec, to spec and integration test every part of my application but any attempt I have had to integration test the canvas has come up... unsuccessful.  I wrote a jQuery plugin that handles interaction with the canvas as well as initializing it.

I wanted to Intergration test the actual drawing on the canvas, making sure that when you call something like

```
$("canvas").draw("lineTo", 10, 10)
```

there is actually a line created on the canvas element at the points (10,10). This is what has proved changeling, I have tried to use the contextual method getImageData() on any drawn pixels. This has lead me into a hole, no matter how I query the canvas I get pixel data representing a black transparent pixel, which by the MDC says I am querying the canvas out of context.

This I think is an issue with the Jasmine gem with RoR.  If I could solve that issue I would be golden but it is not the only solution I am willing to accept.  I really would like to help think of an effective way to integration test the canvas even if I am not actually checking the pixel data directly.

Thanks any one for your help, this is really run me into a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a tool, js-imagediff, which integrates with Jasmine for testing canvas.  You can see an example here: [unit testing canvas with javascript imagediff and jasmine](http://humblesoftware.github.com/js-imagediff/test.html).  Let me know if this is useful.

It does use getImageData to do the diff, however.  Are you getting specific errors with that call?  Or do you have a link to the MDC page you are referring to?

Comment: What cool matcher set, the hard part would be producing what you want from the canvas to test against

Comment: So in my case, I use this for regression testing, rather than BDD.  I test a stable version of a project against the development version.

To use this in BDD, one could create small tests by drawing on a canvas manually and writing a method to the spec'd canvas.  The only other option I'm aware of is to use a mock canvas and jasmine spies.  I would argue that it is more intuitive to see what your test is verses expecting certain methods to have been invoked on the mock canvas context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nightwatchjs for this... http://nightwatchjs.org/
It has an api for interacting with DOM elements, but it is also extendable.  I've written some example custom commands and assertions which you can use to end-to-end test Canvas based Phaser games, but you can see how it's done and create your own tests which execute calls to the canvas drawing api.

see some examples here: https://github.com/hayesmaker/phase-2-e